# CASE WHEN statement example in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

And I have special companies in our project that has `top_company` value is false.

```
special_companies = [111, 222, 333];
```

And I've wrote following query.

```
SELECT top_company FROM companies
```

and top_company will return boolean output. Now got problem if `top_company` return false, I want to check that each companies are included in `special_companies`. If included yes, I want to return that company as boolean `YES`. And If not included, boolean `NO`.

Comment: Can you please include some sample input and output?  Even if you get an answer, this question isn't going to be very useful to anyone down the road.

Comment: there is no input. output is boolean value, t or f.

Comment: `if top_company return false` ... explain what this means if the query hasn't been run yet.

Comment: Which is your database engine: SQL Server or PostgreSQL? It is strange to provide both tags.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If top_company return false, I want to check that company is included in special_company. If that company is included in special company, i want to return true.

Comment: @trincot My database engine is postgres. Btw, those two database engine is not that different in raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to override the `top_company` value when a company is in the special list:

```
select *,
       case when id in (111,222,333) or top_company
         then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as is_top_or_special
from   companies
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2390a/3)

Or, if you don't need the string `YES`/`NO` output, but pure boolean:

```
select *,
       (id in (111,222,333) or top_company) as is_top_or_special
from   companies
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the feedback, guys. Plus, boy am I tired. xD Need to go to sleep. Plus, I screwed up on that implicit conversion. xD '111' is NOT the same as 111 if the column type is not an string (VARCHAR or otherwise).**SQL SERVER WILL LIKELY CONVERT YOUR ENTIRE COLUMN TO COMPARE THE VALUES.**

SQL Server uses a set-based logic, so you can compare different columns in your CASE statement to return the right value you wish. Depending on your need to return the names of companies not in the list (my guess would be no?), you can even use the predicate to return only those values that are false and then compare the list.

Furthermore, in SQL you can use an inner join and/or subquery to further limit the results to disregard the companies you do not care about. E.G.

`SELECT CASE WHEN A.top_companies = FALSE THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS [COLUMN_NAME]
      , B.special_companies
FROM TABLEA AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT special_companies 
           FROM   TABLEB
           WHERE  special_companies IN (111, 222, 333) ) AS B ON B.SOMEKEY = A.SOMEKEY`

However, my original guess from your special_companies = 111, 222, 333 was that it was in the same table. Hence using the predicate to filter the list, which is not only faster, but likely can offer performance boosts if the list gets big through indexing.

Otherwise, your query will use an INDEX_SCAN on the **entire** table, dragging down performance as the table gets larger. It is considered best practice to only return the results you want to see, hence the use of the predicate to limit the data sets.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).